# Function to dictate the replacements in re.sub method (Python)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Trying to use regex to perform substitutions on a string.

```
re.sub(regex, repl_func, content)
```

The problem is that I do not understand how the replacement will occur via the `repl_func` when I need the substitution to be dependent on the matching object from that `regex`; i.e. I will use that matched object as a dictionary key to get the matching value with which that particular object needs to be replaced.

```
    for mobj in re.finditer(regex, content):
        t = mobj.lastgroup
        v = match_obj.group(t)

        if t == 'NAME':
            ...
        elif t == '\n':
            ...
```

I have tried to iterate all the matching objects, as seen above, but cannot figure out how to apply the re.sub. If I understand correctly, the `repl_function` in my first code segment needs to somehow *know* which is the matched object from that regex.

Any ideas, especially using code will be much appreciated cause I am only just now starting with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `re.sub()` function passes the matched object to `repl_function` as an argument and replaces the returned result from that function with the matched string. If you want to replace the matched object with a particular string in a dictionary you can simply use a function to handle that:

```
def repl_func(matched_obj):
    my_dict = {'NAME':'rep1', '\n':'rep2'}
    try:
        match = matched_obj.group(0)
    except AttributeError:
        matched = ''
        # Or raise an exception
    else:
        return my_dict.get(match, '')

re.sub(regex, repl_func, content)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) are pretty clear on this one:

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of `pattern` in string by the replacement `repl`.
>
> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of `pattern`. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

Comment: Silly me, did not read well that part of the doc. I wish they had a better example. Sorry, but could only accept one answer and choose the older one.